# How to avoid the vim omnicomplete menu closing when entering the parameter list?

Tags: vim, parameters, omnicomplete

I’m actively using it for `Python` and `C++` development and it’s kind of frustrating that the menu always closes on me when I enter the function parentheses, because that’s normally when I need most of the help (types and order of parameters).

Comment: What plugins are you using?

Comment: For C++: clang_complete. Python: pydoc.vim and rope-vim. Happens in every language, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's *omni completion* does not work exactly like *Intellisense* in IDEs; it helps completing an identifier or function name, but has no notion of function arguments and their types. That means: It can help you with typing `frobnize`, may even show the function prototype `frobnize(Foo, Bar)`, but cannot help you with completing the function arguments. For that, the completion function would need to consider the full underlying syntax and the previous context, which most don't.

The only aid that some completions offer is that the function prototype is shown in the preview window (with `:set completeopt+=preview`, which is the default). The preview window stays open after the completion, so you still have the last function prototype visible. However, not all completions provide this information.

Comment: I don’t get it, it should be EASY for vim to keep the menu open until I reach the corresponding `)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, for Vim the completion is done as you complete `frobnize`, and without active completion, no menu. The challenge is to write an IDE-like completion over the whole function, but that requires a more intelligent completion function.

Comment: @Profpatsch the source code is available, if it's so easy to add.  :)  You might also check out `:help CursorHold-example` for an idea of another way to keep the preview window tracking what you're doing.  My own workflow usually just entails a lot of `<C-W>]` to split the window and see the function prototype I don't remember.

Comment: Well, I guess as long as the functions don’t have five or six parameters I can remember. Plus, I do have the preview window, even if that isn’t as productive (have to look to the top of the screen).